# What does the phrase "You can say that again!" represent?

Tags: meaning, phrases

The following paragraph is from a story "Ghost in the city"

- "You can say that again!" chimed Barbara after I explained how difficult I felt the test had been.

Can someone please explain what the speaker was trying to say?
In my understanding so far, *You can say that* means *You can tell/ask me again if you have any problem!*

Please correct me!

Comment: _You bet!_ ...see Dictionary.com's [definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/you-can-say-that-again)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a statement of concurrence and agreement. It indicates that the speaker agrees with the previous statement and wishes to reinforce it.

Similar phrases, like "you bet" and "absolutely!", means essentially the same thing.

The phrase "you can say that again" (usually with an exclamation mark at the end) is, in my experience, somewhat casual or familiar.

Also see [this definition at TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/you+can+say+that+again).